# TYPO3 with YAG Extension no theme to choose FE error

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, yag

i have a simple web server at strato.de on which TYPO3 (v7.6.9) is installed. Next I tried to use the YAG (v4.1.2) (Yet Another Gallery) Extension. What I've done:

1. install YAG from TER (includes pt_extbase, pt_extlist)
2. create YAG sysfolder
3. create extension template which includes '[yag] Yet Another Gallery (yag)'
4. create some albums / galleries and upload images
5. add new content by plugin:

   - Plugin Mode: Gallery List
   - Choose some sources
   - Theme: Nothing to choose (empty select boy)

Install a new Theme Package, noting changes

If i try it without any theme I got a FE error:

> The theme identifier was not set. Please check your TypoScript configuration.

I don't now what I can do. Perhaps someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you did everything right.
Look again if the template is correct and active on the page you want it to be. Clear all caches.
I had a similar problem before and those were the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the file \typo3conf\ext\yag\Configuration\TypoScript\Backend\setup.txt to *S*etup.txt (uppercase S).

Clear the cache, try again.

This is some kind of bug. This trick worked for me in both TYPO3 v7 and v8.